# Making divs appear using jquery with an anchor tag trigger

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey so I was wondering how I could go about making a section of the webpage slide down, revealing another div behind it. I wanted the trigger for this to be clicking on an  tag (though if that's not possible then I can change that...)

How would I structure this and what jquery and CSS would be suitable? I have experience in HTML and CSS but almost none in jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you done? recreate your layout in jsfiddle.com and post a link here.

Comment: just go to api.jquery.com and read about `click` and `slideDown(), slideUp() and slideToggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for you to play with:

```
<a id="myLink">Click me</a>
<div id="mySlider">Tada!</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $('#mySlider').slideDown();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/txcbA/

Answer (score 0):

you could use an onclick attribute inside the anchor tag, similar to the following:

```
<a id="mydiv" onclick=myfunction()>text</a>
```

then inside of a script tag in the head of the html document, define myfunction().
myfunction() would show the nested div, which would initially be set to hidden -- possibly using css.

```
myfunction()
{
    $('#nested_div').show();
}
```

this is assuming the id of the nested div is "nested_div."
you would also have to make sure a jquery library is 1)linked via the html page, and 2)located at the specified path.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show and hide it with the same button, use `slideToggle()` instead of slideDown:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $("#div").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$('.tag').click(function(){
    ($('#top').css("margin-top")=="0px") ? $('#top').animate({marginTop:"100px"},500) : $('#top').animate({marginTop:"0px"},500); 
});
```

created a jsFiddle with a working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Kh3GE/

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Just use   $("#div").slideToggle();

with the function that is triggering on click event of anchor tag.

```
$(function()
  {
      $('#dropIt').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.dropdown').slideToggle(2000);
        });
  });
```

Here's the reference: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GpCBy)